# Find a point on a plane so that the position vector of R is perpendicular to the plane.

Tags: linear-algebra

3 points: $A = (3,4,8), B=(1,1,2)$ and $C=(-1,7,5)$ which are contained in the plane $\Pi$.

I am trying to find a point R on the plane so that the position vector of R $\vec{(OR)}$ is perpendicular to $\Pi$.

I have the cartesian for $\Pi$ which is $27x+18x-18z=9$ the normal **n** being $(27,18,-18)$. I am stuck on what to do next?

I am thinking of doing something like $\vec{OR}\cdot$ **n** $=0$. But I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal is of the form $<x,y,z>=t<3,2,-2>$ So $x=3t,y=2t,z=-2t$ Substitute in the plane equation to find t to be $1/17$ Plug this t value in my equation above to find the point on te plane

Comment: So I get $<\frac13,\frac29,-\frac29>$ as my R?

Comment: there is a negative in the z

Comment: Yes sorry I was editing it. So it comes out as the above then?

Comment: That's what I got

Comment: If you don't mind going further, if I wanted to find the distance from the origin to $\Pi$ would I treat it as a line or just a point?

Comment: The distance from O to the plane is the distance from O to the point we just found. That can be done with the Pythagorean Theorem

Comment: Sorry, how did you get $(\frac39,\frac29,\frac29)$ since $27(3t)+18(2t)-18(-2t)=9$ gives $81t+36t+36t=9$ not $81t=9$?

Comment: Yes, you are right, the t value becomes 1/17. It's getting late over here....